# How to localize AppBar buttons

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, localization

I have a Windows 8 Metro application created from the Grid Application template. I need to localize the buttons in the AppBar. Normaly I use x:Uid and .resw for localization but this does not work for the navigation buttons in AppBar.

For example, for the Home button I need to localize the "Home" text. The "Home" text is defined in StandardStyles.xaml as follows:

```
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Home"/>
```

I tried defining HomeButton.AutomationProperties.Name in resw but I get

> Unable to resolve property 'AutomationProperties.Name' while processing properties for Uid

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx where it shows how to use the right RESW syntax for an attached property like this.  So if you are using the button styles you could do something like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource HomeAppBarButtonStyle}" x:Uid="HomeButton" />
```

And then in your RESW you'd have:

```
HomeButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

as your key value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It might be worth noting that currently this functionality only works if your resources file has the default Resources.resw filename.

Comment: I tried adding the uid to my button style and this didn't work, so it looks like you can't have localised properties in a style.

Comment: Looks like that article has been removed. Is there a replacement? Is this still the recommended way to go?